# java.lang.ClassCastException even though I am casting it to the extended class

Tags: java, mongodb

I am trying to setup a [mongo-hadoop](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop) driver extensions for the hadoop streaming jobs I have written for the python plugin [dumbo](https://github.com/klbostee/dumbo).

The dumbo project needs me to use the TypedBytesWritable class. So I made a new InputFormat & RecordReader like so:

```
package com.mongodb.hadoop;

public class TypedBytesTableInputFormat implements InputFormat<TypedBytesWritable, TypedBytesWritable> {

@Override
public RecordReader<TypedBytesWritable, TypedBytesWritable> getRecordReader(InputSplit split, 
                                                                            JobConf job,
                                                                            Reporter reporter) {

    if (!(split instanceof MongoInputSplit))
        throw new IllegalStateException("Creation of a new RecordReader requires a MongoInputSplit instance.");

    final MongoInputSplit mis = (MongoInputSplit) split;

    //**THE FOLLOWING LINE THROWS THE ERROR**
    return (RecordReader<TypedBytesWritable, TypedBytesWritable>) new TypedBytesMongoRecordReader(mis);
}
```

And here is the extended RecordReader:

```
package com.mongodb.hadoop.input;
...
...
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.RecordReader;
...
...

public class TypedBytesMongoRecordReader extends RecordReader<TypedBytesWritable, TypedBytesWritable> {

public TypedBytesMongoRecordReader(MongoInputSplit mis) {
    _cursor = mis.getCursor();
}

@Override
public void close() {
    if ( _cursor != null )
        _cursor.close();
}
```

But when I run the job, it throws this error. I am not sure why, it is a child of the RecordReader. What am I doing wrong? Here is the API doc for the RecordReader class. I thought I was doing everything correctly:

http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/RecordReader.html

I do get a warning on the line that is being cast to a RecordReader, but no errors, and it builds the jar just fine. The warning:

```
Type safety: Unchecked cast from TypedBytesMongoRecordReader to RecordReader<TypedBytesWritable,TypedBytesWritable>
```

Comment: Do the classes live in the same ClassLoader?

Comment: Oh dangit. One is in package com.mongodb.hadoop and the other is in package com.mongodb.hadoop.input; That would cause my problems? Or did you mean something else? I am new to Java. :)

Comment: You shouldn't need a cast. If you've inherited correctly then due to polymorphism. Remove the cast and see what the compiler says.

Comment: It won't let me compile with this error: `Type mismatch: cannot convert from TypedBytesMongoRecordReader to RecordReader<TypedBytesWritable,TypedBytesWritable>`

Comment: It wants my TypedBytesMongoRecordReader to implement RecordReader as well as extend (the mongo-hadoop original code doesn't do this). Change the return type to TypedBytesMongoRecordReader, or cast to RecordReader like I originally have

Comment: Oh wait...I think implementing it as well may have worked! I will have to write the output class as well, but no errors!

Comment: It's not reading any of the records though, even though the job successfully sees over 80K of records...Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public <T extends RecordReader<TypedBytesWritable, TypedBytesWritable>> T getRecordReader(InputSplit split, JobConf job, Reporter reporter) {

    if (!(split instanceof MongoInputSplit))
        throw new IllegalStateException("Creation of a new RecordReader requires a MongoInputSplit instance.");

    final MongoInputSplit mis = (MongoInputSplit) split;

    return new TypedBytesMongoRecordReader(mis); // you may need a cast (T) - try it without first
}
```